# VC++ 2010 compile error: class contains explicit override but does not derive from an interface that contains the function declaration

Tags: .net, visual-c++, namespaces

I'm working on a C++ .NET project, and I have a .lib library from a vendor to talk to their specific hardware.
I get a compile error "error C3254: 'class contains explicit override 'GetLastWin32Error' but does not derive from an interface that contains the function declaration"  from the header file, but that function doesn't exist, it's just called GetLastError.

I get a second compile error on the function saying it has an illegally qualified name in the member declaration.

This compiles fine in the vendor's example app and my own command-line app, so I think this is related to .NET, and it looks like a namespace collision.

Is there an easy way to fix this with something like a namespace change?

Comment: Compile with /clr instead of /clr:pure to avoid a macro in Winbase.h